# Preferred database management system for Objective-C (iPhone apps)

Tags: iphone, mysql, objective-c, database, sqlite

What would you say is the best candidate for a DBMS for use in iPhone apps? The database would be online, not on the device, so a back-end updating administration interface would be most beneficial (like phpMyAdmin is for MySQL).

I only know of MySQL (not sure if it can be used for iPhone with satisfactory results), and SQL Lite, are there any other managements systems that would be great for performance as well be reliable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the database is online, I wouldn't recommend any kind of management system on the device. I would probably recommend implementing some kind of web service and communicate to the database server and its own DBMS via the web service.

Answer (score 4):

the choice of the DBMS has nothing to do with the iphone .. likely the iphone will connect to a web service (weither SOAP or REST). the web service will be the one using the database not the device.

Answer (score 1):

Anriëtte, I seem to have bumped into two common scenarios

- For my corporate clients, they use SQL server as their database and .Net as their server API.
- For my non-corporate clients, we usually use MySQL with a PHP or a Ruby on Rails server.

In both cases, I use JSON on the iPhone to talk to REST services on their servers.  This works great.

Both DBMS above have good management tools.  I usually use the MySQL GUI tools or SQL Server GUI tools to administer the database.  Lots of people (not me) like the PHP MySQL admin tools because they are web based.  Please do not use a personal database on the server like SQLite, Access of FileMaker, they do not scale.

I did once write an Objective-C program that accessed MySQL using its C++ libraries, not a good idea.

My advice: Ruby on Rails REST using JSON on top of a MySQL database on the server side.